# How to proxy both references of "this" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have the following function that is a callback for a function (in other words, "this" refers to what the callback passed):

```
afunction("onclick", callbackfunction)
function callbackfunction() {
   console.log(this); // This refers to item clicked
}
```

Instead of referring to just the item clicked I want to include a reference to the parent object. Normally I would use:

```
afunction("onclick", $.proxy(callbackfunction, this))
```

However this makes it such that I can't get the item clicked anymore. Is there a way I could keep both so that I could have access within the callbackfunction both the "proxy" "this" and the item clicked "this"?

Comment: When you mean parent object, do you mean `parentNode`?

Comment: parent object meaning, whatever "this" normally refers to outside the callback. Could be the "window" object, which is what it is typically.

Comment: The answer that was deleted was correct, you can grab the clicked element from the event object. If `e` is really undefined as you said, that's something really wrong in the way `afunction` is binding the event (note that you have to change your callback signature to `function callbackfunction() {...`)

Comment: That is the case for a JQuery binding click event. Certain javascript APIs may not set e and instead may use "this" instead. One cannot guarantee "e" to be available for other callback functions that may use "this" to refer to the object clicked.

Comment: It's not jQuery that sets `e`, it's the browser (granted, jQuery modifies it). If you bind with addEventListener (the standard) or attachEvent (oldIE), the event object will always be passed automatically. The same is true if you bind with `element.onclick = function(){}`. So, as I said, you are either confused, or there's something really wrong going on in afunction. Can you show the code for that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't have two meanings of `this`, one would need to be passed as an argument.

One possibility using `$.proxy` would be to pass `null` as the `thisArg` value. That will cause the `this` to not be bound. When the event occurs, the `this` value will be the expected value set by the caller.

Then you can pass the enclosing `this` as an argument to be received by the function's first parameter.

```
afunction("onclick", $.proxy(callbackfunction, null, this));
```

---

This functionality of passing `null` requires jQuery 1.9 or later.

From the [`$.proxy` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

> **As of jQuery 1.9**, when the context is `null` or `undefined` the the proxied function will be called with the same this object as the proxy was called with. This allows `$.proxy()` to be used to partially apply the arguments of a function without changing the context.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
var self = this;
afunction("onclick", function(evt){
    var clicked = this;
    anotherfunction(clicked,self);
});
```